# Make the if statement case insensitive in bash

Tags: bash, curl, header, case-insensitive, lowercase

My code is going to check headers by using curl. Sometimes the headers and their values are shown with uppercase letters, sometimes with lowercase letters.

For example `X-Requested-Id` can be found like `x-requested-id` or `X-Requested-ID`.

How can I make the if statement case insensitive?

```
if [[ $check_headers == "X-Requested-Id"* ]]; then
```

Comment: try `shopt -s nocasematch`

Comment: Note that setting `nocasematch` will affect other types of pattern matching as well, provided they're done by the shell (e.g. filename wildcards, and `[[ string =~ regex ]]`, but *not* matching done by `grep`, `sed`, etc). You might or might not want this, so be prepared to turn `nocasematch` on and off as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Bash 4 or newer, you can use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to lowercase the string:

```sh
if [[ ${check_headers,,} == "x-requested-id"* ]]; then
```

Comment: @sof31 make sure the right-hand side is lowercase too.

Comment: @sof31; if you're (still) having problems getting this answer to work, consider asking a new question and providing the details to allow us to reproduce the issue

Comment: @markp-fuso The problem solved. I needed to make to right-hand side of the if statement lowercase as glen jackman said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to Bash 4 (or newer), you can define a separate variable as lowercase and then reference the 'lowercase' variable as needed, eg:

```
$ myvar='ABC_def'
$ typeset -l myvar_lower="${myvar}"
$ echo "${myvar_lower}"
abc_def
```

Back to OPs issue:

```
typeset -l check_headers_lower="${check_headers}"

if [[ "${check_headers_lower}" == "X-Requested-Id"* ]]; then
```

**NOTES:**

- there's nothing to keep you from defining the original variable as lowercase as long as you're sure there will be no follow-on requirement for the data in its original case
- changing the case of a variable will not affect the current value of the variable; **a)** `x=A; typeset -l x; echo "${x}"` => `A` **b)** `typeset -l x; x=A; echo "${x}"` => `a` **c)** `typeset -l x=A; echo "${x}"` => `a` **d)** `x=A; typeset -l x="${x}"; echo "${x}"` => `a`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer every other suggestion already made here, but...

*If*, in a pinch, you don't remember those syntaxes, and for some reason don't have time to look them up, remember that if just checks the return value of it's operands, so you can always use another program. (Ick, I hate running unnecessary processes, but as I said, it's a hack to remember...)

```
if grep -i x-requested-id <<< "$check_headers" # grep -i is case-insensitive
```

## EDIT

To elaborate Benjamin's solution, which I agree is excellent, try this:

```
$: [[ X == x ]] && echo ok || echo no # case sensitive, fails
no
$: ( shopt -s nocasematch; [[ X == x ]] && echo ok || echo no; ) # in a subshell
ok
$: [[ X == x ]] && echo ok || echo no # back to normal
no
```

Wrapping it in a subshell limits the `nocasematch`'s scope.

You say his solution "doesn't work". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Works fine, but looking for a lighter solution to avoid more processes.

Benjamin's solution seems easy to use but it doesn't work for me however I have bash version 5.
Any idea?

Comment: It works now. The problem was the I didn't write the right-hand side of the if statement in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Using `nocasematch` shell option. Like what *Gordon Davisson* mentioned in the comments, it should be disabled after the test and beware of other pattern matching like using the `=~` operator.

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $check_headers == "X-Requested-Id"* ]]; then
 ...
fi
shopt -u nocasematch
```

---

Like what @Benjamin W. mentioned in the comment it is a good practice to check first the status of the value `shopt`.

Using `eval`

```
oldvalue=$(shopt -p nocasematch)
shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $check_headers == "X-Requested-Id"* ]]; then
     ...
fi

eval "$oldvalue"
```

---

I would check the status of the `shopt` first before enabling it, and later disable it.

Without the `eval`, something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if ! shopt -q nocasematch; then
  shopt -s nocasematch
  on=1
fi

if [[ $check_headers == "X-Requested-Id"* ]]; then
  ....
fi

if ((on)); then 
  shopt -u nocasematch
  on=0
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying **beware of other pattern matching like using the =~ operator.** ? What would be the difference if I use =~ or == with shopt?

Comment: The `=~` is matching a regex and if it `nocasematch` is enabled then it might do some unintentional outcome.

Comment: If instead of blindly turning on and off you want to make sure the option is set to its previous value, you can do something like `oldvalue=$(shopt -p nocasematch); shopt -s nocasematch` and then later `eval "$oldvalue"`.